# Managing on-click structures in mobile from the backend

Tags: c#, .net, flutter, rest, mobile

I encountered such a problem in a project.
I have a mobile app running on a flutter. Sometimes, a button, a slider image or similar structures in the mobile app do not know where the mobile app should go.
It needs to learn from the json from the backend. For example, we have a slider structure.
When the first slide is clicked, it should go to the product under a category, when the second slide is clicked, it should open another page in the app, and when the third slide is clicked, it should go to google with an outlink.
Similarly, when a button is clicked within the application, the button should open another page within the application.
What kind of structure should I set up in such a situation? This structure should also be manageable by the admin in the backend.
For example, as in the first, second, and third slide, the values ​​here must be changeable.
I use .net rest api as backend.

Comment: You have JSON that is serialized on the front end and then deserialized.  Any options in the front end must be added to the JSON and then after deserialized send different queries to the database.

Comment: @jdweng  Can you give an example so that I can understand

Comment: See https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: I'm talking about the on-click structure. Database design etc.

Comment: The on-click are events and in the event handlers you add flutter code like in the link above.  The simple cases like in following example just return fixed values.  You want more complicated code that gets data from your backend : https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/gestures/ripples